# Xcode 7.3 simulator and new iDevices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7, iphone-se

When will the new iPhone SE and Ipad Pro 9.7" simulators be added? I can't find them in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: Not sure whether they will ever be added, b/c their screen sizes are the same as other devices.

Comment: Well there is a 6S and 6 simulator, and they have the same screens.

Comment: Good point actually...

Comment: They do have different hardware as well. I just find it odd they are missing.

Comment: Well, it will come eventually. Maybe in the next update of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question but I guess they won't be added. When the iPad Pro got out, they added its simulator immediately. In fact I think it was on the betas of Xcode 7.

As for these new devices, the iPhone SE has the same resolution as the iPhone 5S. It's a 64 bits too and they both lack 3D Touch. My guess is there are iPhone 6 and 6s simulator because the latter has 3D Touch unlike the former. 
The new iPad Pro is virtually the same as iPad Air 2.

In conclusion, that's no big deal ;)